# Lock-Free Concurrent Linked List in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, linked-list

I would like to use a Linked List like the one described in [this](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/l/o/lock_free_linked_lists_using_compare_and_3368.pdf) paper.
However, I didn't find any Java implementation in the web.

If no java implementation of the above mentioned Linked List exists, I think, I would use the `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>`. Is this a good choice (it is not really a linked list)?

If it's not a good choice, does anyone know of a reliable concurrent (thread-safe) wait-free(lock-free) Linked List implementation in Java?

Comment: It's not lock-free in any shape of form (it does use locks for adding/removing) - doh target comment gone... (it was regarding LinkedBlockingDeque)

Comment: Well, the big question is, why do you think you want a concurrent list of any shape or form? Most List methods don't make sense on a shared concurrent structure. Why would you get the nth element? What does it mean anyway to get the nth element? Things like size are ephemeral and of no value apart from for monitoring. Can you explain a bit more about how you want to use this? http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jsr.166-concurrency/6321

Comment: I want to implement a singleton "physical" buffer, which is used by n "logical" buffers, where each logical buffer is defined only by its start and end elements, s.t. I don't have a redundant representation of my data in memory.

Comment: well, I still don't understand what problem you are trying to solve, you have only outlined a solution. Often in a concurrent algorithm you do need to trade memory for isolation though, the costs of coordinating access and modification to the same memory can be prohibitive. See Guy Steele for example http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Thinking-Parallel-Programming

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is a superb lock free queue and does what a concurrent single linked list can do.
A small warning: if you dont use poll or peek and only iterator() (+.remove()) it will leak memory.

It's an outstanding [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Comment: JDK 7 has a ConcurrentLinkedDeque

Comment: let's say, i want the ConcurrentLinkedDeque, how safe is installing the current jdk7 preview version?

Comment: actually it's fairly simple to implement it in Java (both queue, deque). Thanks to the GC, there is no ABA. Overall concurrent/lock-free algos are times easier if you have GC... Or just to grab the source form the JDK7 and run it at w/ JDK6, you will (most likely) need Unsafe but that's not an issue, if you drop the code in bootstrap path. To make sure I am not going wrong I will check the latest JDK7 source code and tell if the code can be safely backported (copied) into jdk6

Comment: @betsss I feel like that is overkill.  The OP can just go to http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/ and download the jar.  It should be very stable considering it will be introduced with Java 7 (which should be going live soon).

Comment: yeah it looks it can be safely copied into and run w/ jdk6

Comment: actually forgot that (about CLD): "Empirically, microbenchmarks suggest that this class adds about 40% overhead relative to ConcurrentLinkedQueue, which feels as good as we can hope for." So unless really needed to do pollLast()...

Comment: If you're trying to achieve a ConcurrentLinkedList you can imagine the added overhead will be a good amount more.  But I agree a ConcurrentLinkedQueue would be best to use.

Comment: If I rethink my application, I think it should be relatively easy to solve my problem with a queue instead of a Linked List. I will just have to reimplement some of the already written stuff.

Comment: Can we sort concurrent linked queue using collections.sort() ?? I don't think so, but we can use collections.sort() on a linked list. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Queues do not support the `get(int)` method for random access, so any type of `Queue` is not a substitute for a `List`.