# Non-blocking algorithm to modify a List<V> in Java

Tags: java, atomic, nonblocking, lock-free, compare-and-swap

The use case requires me not to block any thread while retrieving or putting values into a `List<V>`. I have been looking at [compare-and-swap algorithms](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04186/) that require you to implement a datastructure yourself. I would like to use an existing implementation of Collection such as an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` and achieve a lock-free insertion and look up of elements. There is an option to have `AtomicReferenceArray<E>`. But I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this for a variable-sized list.

Comment: There is the [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) which is lock free. If you want the full functionality of a `List` then you will need to look at external libraries.

Comment: List<String> sinchronizedList = Collections.sinchronizedList(yourList);

Comment: Both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are not threadsafe and thus lock-free. So you want to have a thread safe implementation, but without locks? Seems a bit contrary to me.

Comment: @bigdestroyer: The OP wants to avoid synchronized datastructures. Synchronized is simply not *lock-free*.

Comment: Do you want sincronization without sincronization?

Comment: @bigdestroyer: no, *lock-free* means that there are no locks. The algorithms can run in parallel and perform a *compare-and-swap* in the end, a hardware-based atomic instruction to reduce the overhead.

Comment: @Zhedar: see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

Comment: @BoristheSpider `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is really interesting. Any similar lock-free collections and pointers to external libraries?

Comment: @bigdestroyer Sorry, but you obviously have no clue what the OP is asking for. I would suggest that you do not comment in these cases, it is somewhat unhelpful.

Comment: @user592748, this is an extremely complicated problem. I don't know of any more complex lock-free collections apart from Skip Lists. For what the JDK has to offer, examine [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: Just because I'm curious: Why do you need lock-free synchronization? Is it a real-time application? Are you working on an embedded system?

Comment: @OP Is this question a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724995/lock-free-concurrent-linked-list-in-java)?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, it is a similar question. I need something like `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`. However, the team is using 1.6. I need to get the last element. I am not sure how to do that yet

Comment: @slartidan a real-time application. No. not embedded.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is the read the [original paper](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf) and go from there.

Comment: just use volatile keyword

Comment: What happened to the answer with busy-waiting? I am not sure of the correctness of this because all CAS algorithms I have seen make use of atomic references. Besides, it looks just too simple. There are papers written on CAS-based data structures and I wouldn't believe that would be the case if a simple busy-waiting algorithm would be a substitute. And on these ground, I wouldn't try that approach.